# Calendar in list but not in sidebar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I loaded the My Meetups Calendar from meetup.com into my gmail account which I synchronize with Calendar.app. The My Meet up a calendar is in the calendars list in the menu, but not in the sidebar, and that means I have to specifically open a separate window to see the events on my meetups.

Illustration:[image]

How can I fix thhis?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by going to Preferences (`⌘+,`) -> Accounts -> Google Account -> Delegation (tab) -> Click on My Meetups.

I can now see the meetups in the calendar :)

**Warning**: This is a viable solution only, of course, if you don't use the delegation feature -> If you do, you will give (unneccesary?) access to your Meet ups to your delegates, which may not be what you want.